# Remove duplicates appearing within a certain time period using Teradata or sql

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a dataset containing an ID variable, a date, and several agents (see example below). The agents have been tested several times per patient and I want to filter for every ID the first one to appear and remove all the other tests appearing within 4 weeks after the first. After this, I again want to filter the first one and remove all the others appearing within 4 weeks - throughout the whole dataset. I also generated variables showing the week, month and year.

```
     ID Date        Week Month Year  Agent
1    1  2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent1
2    1  2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent2 
3    1  2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent3 
4    1  2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent4 
5    1  2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent1 
6    1  2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent2 
7    1  2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent3
8    1  2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent4
9    1  2010-12-27  52   12    2010  Agent1
10   1  2010-12-27  52   12    2010  Agent2
11   1  2010-12-27  52   12    2010  Agent3
12   1  2010-12-27  52   12    2010  Agent4
13   1  2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent1
14   1  2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent2
15   1  2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent3
16   1  2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent4
17   1  2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent1
18   1  2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent2
19   1  2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent3
20   1  2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent4
```

expected output

```
     ID Date        Week Month Year  Agent
1    1  2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent1
2    1  2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent2 
3    1  2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent3 
4    1  2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent4 
13   1  2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent1
14   1  2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent2
15   1  2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent3
16   1  2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent4
```

Comment: This kind of logic can't be solved without iterative processing. Either a loop in a Stored Procedure (here you process all rows within 4 weeks) or a Recursive Select (Materialize the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTTION BY ID, Agent ORDER BY datecol)` in a Volatile Table). Sorry, no time for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I have solution for this using R ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64696494/remove-duplicates-appearing-within-a-certain-time-period ) but I want to do it sql or teradata. Thanks