# Remove duplicates appearing within a certain time period using sql or Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a dataset containing an ID variable, a date, and several agents (see example below). The agents have been tested several times per patient and I want to filter for every ID the first one to appear and remove all the other tests appearing within 4 weeks after the first. After this, I again want to filter the first one and remove all the others appearing within 4 weeks - throughout the whole dataset. I also generated variables showing the week, month and year.

```
     ID Date        Week Month Year  Agent
1    10 2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent1
2    12 2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent2 
3    13 2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent3 
4    14 2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent4 
5    10 2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent1 
6    12 2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent2 
7    13 2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent3
8    14 2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent4
9    10 2010-12-27  52   12    2010  Agent1
10   12 2010-12-27  52   12    2010  Agent2
11   13 2010-12-27  52   12    2010  Agent3
12   14 2010-12-27  52   12    2010  Agent4
13   10 2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent1
14   12 2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent2
15   13 2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent3
16   14 2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent4
17   10 2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent1
18   12 2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent2
19   13 2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent3
20   14 2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent4
```

and what I need is this:

```
     ID Date        Week Month Year  Agent
1    10 2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent1
2    12 2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent2 
3    13 2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent3 
4    14 2010-12-09  49   12    2010  Agent4 
13   10 2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent1
14   12 2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent2
15   13 2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent3
16   14 2011-01-14  2    1     2011  Agent4
```

I'm happy about any help!

Comment: I have solution for this using R ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64696494/remove-duplicates-appearing-within-a-certain-time-period ) but I want to do it sql or teradata. Thanks

Comment: Does the first value of each row belong to any column?

Comment: Are the duplicate rows intentional? For example, rows 4 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your true duplicates are intentional, you can use a couple of window functions (row_number and min over) combined with qualify to filter on those window functions.  I named your first column with the row numbers rn just to include it in the output.

```
    select
    t.*,
    min(theDate) over (partition by id order by theDate) as minDate,
    theDate - minDate as daysBetween
    from
    <your table> t
    qualify (daysBetween > 28 --exclude rows within 28 days from first date
    or daysBetween = 0  )    -- keep the first row for each id)

    --get rid of true duplicates
    and row_number() over (partition by id,theDate,agent order by rn) = 1
    
    order by rn
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the help. Using above query I'm able to get the two rows if same id occurs after 28 days, but after the 2nd row if we have repetition of same id after 28 days can we get the third row which which data is 28 days after second row & so on.

Comment: Here the example in R for you're reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64696494/remove-duplicates-appearing-within-a-certain-time-period  where Agent 1 repeating multiple times after 4 weeks

Comment: Using the data from your other question, the query is returning what you have as the desired result in that question.